# Sencha Ext JS JSON stores load slowly

Tags: extjs, loading

I loaded JSON file to store but i got 0.8 second loading time.
Why?

**This is the store create and the alert that show me the loading time:**

```
var start = new Date();
var store = Ext.create('ExtDoc.stores.extwindow.ExtDocGridStore');
store.initStore("file.json");

store.load({
                callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                if(success == true){
                                                var end = new Date();
                                                var duration = end - start;
                                                alert(duration/1000);
                                }
                }
});
```

**ExtDoc.stores.extwindow.ExtDocGridStore file:**

```
Ext.define('ExtDoc.stores.extwindow.ExtDocGridStore', {
                requires:[            'ExtDoc.models.extwindow.ExtDocGridModel'],
                extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
                model: 'ExtDoc.models.extwindow.ExtDocGridModel',
                proxy: {
                                type: 'ajax',
                    pageParam: false,
                    startParam: false,
                    limitParam: false,
                                noCache: false,
                                method: 'GET',
                                reader: {
                                                async: false,
                                                type: 'json',
                                                rootProperty: ''
                                }
                },
                initStore: function(dataUrl){
                                this.getProxy().setUrl(dataUrl);
                }
});
```

**file.json:**

```
empty file
```

Comment: Because that's how long it takes your server to respond.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli but antother json files load more quick... how can i check it?